# ajax tab not reflect html page change

Tags: html, ajax

i use tab in my one html page and load some other pages by using ajax on that same page but the problem is that html page not reflect the changes it remain same as before,is there any kind of cache problem or other i use localhost for the same xampp server.
js code is

```
var containerId = '#tabs-container';
var tabsId = '#tabs';

$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(tabsId + ' LI.current A').length > 0){
        loadTab($(tabsId + ' LI.current A'));
    }

    $(tabsId + ' A').click(function(){
        if($(this).parent().hasClass('current')){ return false; }

        $(tabsId + ' LI.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');

        loadTab($(this));     
        return false;
    });
});
function loadTab(tabObj){
    if(!tabObj || !tabObj.length){ return; }
    $(containerId).addClass('loading');
    $(containerId).fadeOut('fast'); 
    $(containerId).load(tabObj.attr('href'), function(){
        $(containerId).removeClass('loading');
        $(containerId).fadeIn('fast');
    });
}
```

html code is:

```
<ul class="mytabs" id="tabs">
    <li class="current">
        <a href="tabs/room.html">
            Rooms and Suits
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="tabs/dining.html">
            Dining
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="tabs/spa.html">
            Spa &amp; Wellness
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="tabs/wedding.html">
            Wedding
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="tabs/event.html">
            Meetings &amp; Events
        </a>
    </li>
<!-- 
example how to integrate in php
<li>
<a href="wp-content/themes/himachaldastak/sport.php">
Meetings &amp; Events
</a>
</li> -->
</ul>

<div class="mytabs-container" id="tabs-container">
    <img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading.." id="photo_load">
</div>
```

Comment: would be nice if you could make a fiddle about this. would make it way more easy to help

Comment: so nice to hear from you ferdinand, problem is resolved actually right now i use html and ajax request to the server first it show me the data previously stored in the browser had little confusion about basic terms thanks for response